# AWS Route53 Sub-Domain Redirection Design

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

AWS Design Question.

We have **'n' number of static React JS** website to host. Since we have more than 100 website at the moment **( it will keep growing )**, we planned to host the website in s3 bucket.

we **cannot create s3 bucket for each new website** and create an cloud front for each bucket.

so we decided to put all the websites in a **single bucket** with each website in a individual folder, and mount the s3 bucket in a ec2 linux instance apache folder i.e. /var/www and make necessary configuration **(including SSL)**.

so presently, we have a domain(self-managed) e.g '**sample.net**' -> **pointing to the ec2 instance apache server**.

To **access a website** called '**sample-website**' -> [www.sample.net/sample-website](http://www.sample.net/sample-website) apache will server me the website from the bucket which has the folder called sample-website.

Presently we have a another domain called '**sample.com**' in Route53, we would like to **create sub-domain (CNAME record)** in **run-time** and set the value to [www.sample.net/sample-website](http://www.sample.net/sample-website).

> I have written code in python using boto3 to create CNAME record in
> runtime.

Two Questions based on the design:

1 - Can we have **SSL** for '**sample.com**'? as we have SSL certificate for '**sample.net**'

2 - Is there a better way to do it?

Design Image:
[image]

P.S:

Comment: @Marcin at the moment, still unclear about the https part, can we get a free wildcard certificate from aws ACM for the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create sub-domain (CNAME record) in run-time and set the value to [www.sample.net/sample-website](http://www.sample.net/sample-website)

Sadly, you **can't do this**. Route53 is a DNS resolver, and it does not have any notion of URL paths, such as `/sample-website`. You could possibly do it from CloudFront or your load balancers, where you can specify the URL paths.

> Can we have SSL for 'sample.com'? as we have SSL certificate for 'sample.net'

Yes you can. Using AWS ACM you can register a single SSL cert for multiple domains.

Comment: but i can redirect a cname record 'example.sample.com' to sample.net/example , right?

Comment: and can that cname record be https?

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar No it can't. DNS records do not have notion of HTTPS/HTTP, just like with url paths. It must be done on your load balancer, cloudfront or in the app.